# AngularJS ui.router not rendering view [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create simple web application on MEAN stack.

I have a trouble with routing in application. When I make request to index page(localhost:3000/), it works well, but when I am trying to request localhost:3000/exposition page, it responses me JSON instead of html template.

This is my code of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Expotest</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'app/header.tpl.html'"></div>
    <div ui-view class="container-fluid"></div>
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-full/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-full/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-full/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-http-auth/http-auth-interceptor.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/exposition/exposition.js"></script>
    <script src="app/exposition/ExpositionServices.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngCookies',
    'exposition',
    'ui.router'
]);
angular.module('app').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "app/index.tpl.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        });

}]);
angular.module('app').controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location) {

}]);

angular.module('app').controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location) {

}]);
```

I have tried to divide logic of modules in different files.
So, my exposition.js

```
var expositionApp = angular.module('exposition', ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'exposition.services', 'angularMoment']);

expositionApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',

    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider
            .state('exposition', {
                url: "/exposition/",
                templateUrl: 'app/exposition/list.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ExpositionsController'
            })
            .state('exposition.create', {
                url: "/exposition/create/",
                templateUrl: 'app/exposition/create.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ExpositionsController'
            })
            .state('exposition.view', {
                url: "/exposition/:id/",
                templateUrl: 'app/exposition/details.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ExpositionsController'
            })
            .state('exposition.edit', {
                url: "/exposition/:id/edit/",
                templateUrl: 'app/exposition/edit.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ExpositionsController'
            });
    }
]);

expositionApp.controller('ExpositionController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$state', '$location', 'ExpositionUpdateService',
    function ($scope, $resource, $state, $location, ExpositionUpdateService) {
...
}
]);
```

ExpositionService.js

```
var module = angular.module('exposition.services', ['ngResource']);

module.factory('ExpositionUpdateService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('exposition/:id',
        {
            id: '@id'
        },
        {
            'update': {method: 'PUT'}
        },
        {
            'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
        },
        {
            'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
        }
    );
});
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you!

My routes.js

```
var index = require('../routes/index');
var expositions = require('../routes/exposition');
module.exports = function (app){
    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/exposition',expositions);
}
```

And app.js

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src')));
app.use('/vendor',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/vendor')));
app.use('/app',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src/app')));
app.use('/common',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src/common')));
app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src/assets')));
var connect = function(){
    var options = {
        server: {
            socketOptions:{
                keepAlive : 1
            }
        }
    };
    mongoose.connect(config.db,options);
};
connect();
mongoose.connection.on('error',console.log);
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected',connect);
require('./config/routes')(app);
require('./config/express')(app);
```

Comment: If you're getting JSON, that probably means the server is serving one of your API routes. It also looks like your API for expositions might use the same routes that angular does. It might be easier if you put all your API routes under `/api/` or something like that and serve `index.html` for all other routes and let angular handle the rest

Comment: Hi @mzulc Thank you! I have updated my question with providing of app.js and routes.js of my node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

mzulch is correct. This is the first step you need to stake, which will make the server send the index page whatever you throw at it. That is probably overkill but you can finetune.

```
module.exports = function (app){
    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/exposition', index);

}
```

You will also need a `<base>` statement in your index.html

Comment: I changed my routes file like you mentioned, but it still reponses JSON.

Comment: Now it always reponses /index controller.